# Rstudio theme text dims when clicking inside a chunk

Tags: r, themes, rstudio

I've customized a dark theme for Rstudio.  The color I've used for **comments** has odd behavior in .Rmd (R Markdown) documents.  It displays  nice and bright normally, until I click inside a chunk, then the color dims.  It's a small issue, but irritating, and makes the text harder to read.  As I scroll down the document, previously dim sections will return to being bright, then return to being dim when I click in the chunk.  I have also altered the chunk highlighting for better visibility.

In addition, when selecting themes under Global Options, I need to click on the theme twice for it to display in the example box.  For some reason, it seems my system isn't handling the themes as expected.

I'm new to styles/themes/CSS, but I thought there might be an issue with the order my edits were written in.

The edits for the chunk highlighting and comment color are on lines:
101
81

Here is the theme file in question

https://github.com/captaincaed/rstudio/blob/main/vibrant_ink_SB_2.rstheme

Here is a Windows error log (seems to open best in Word, may open in a browser as well)

https://github.com/captaincaed/rstudio/blob/main/Recording_20210119_1453.mht

RStudio
Version 1.4.1103
Windows 10

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're open to other themes, [Atom One (dark)](https://github.com/tkrabel/rstudio_atom_theme) is similar to vibrant ink, except orange and purple are swapped and it's not as 'vibrant'. Maybe it would suit your purpose?

Comment: I'm open to other themes, although I cannot get this one to display properly either.  My editor is really having trouble with themes.

Comment: Perhaps post the issue on https://community.rstudio.com/c/rstudio-ide/9

Comment: Good tip, thank you.